# Regular Expression Doubts

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have string which contains a list of comparison operators and its operands. from this list i want to separate out the operands that only has '=' operator.
`cellvalue = 'var1 == 5\n var2 >= 0.2\n var3 <= 0\n var4 = 5\n var5 = -3.0'`
From this string, i want a list that contains all operands using '=' operator.
that is `list_req1 = ['var4','var5']` and `list_req2 = ['5','-3.0']`. How would i be able to do it using regular expressions?

```
I have tried the following command:
all_signals = []
regx = '([a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)\s*(=)'
for m in re.findall(regx, cellvalue):
        all_signals.append(m[0])
print(all_signals)
this returns: ['var1','var4','var5']



expected: ['var4','var5']
actual: ['var1','var4','var5']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just match a single equals operator surrounded by whitespace like this:

```
re.findall(r'\s=\s', value)
```

The next one is a bit more sophistivated and also captures variable names and numeric values as group(1) and group(2) respectively:

```
re.findall(r'\b(\w+)\s+=\s+([\d.]+)')
```